# Getting a value from a DataTableReader

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made a method that if there is something in the table, it gets the value of it's `MsgID` column and return a value bigger in 1 that what it received, if there is nothing in the table it return 0;

here is the method:

```
public int getMsgNum()
{
    public static string CON_STR = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Database.mdf") + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlDataAdapter daObj = new SqlDataAdapter("Select MAX(MsgID) FROM Msgs", CON_STR);

    DataSet dsObj = new DataSet();
    daObj.Fill(dsObj);
    DataTableReader r = dsObj.Tables[0].CreateDataReader(); 

    if (r.Read())
        return int.Parse(r["MsgID"].ToString()) + 1;

    return 0;
}
```

I run debug and it told me that the problem is in the line

`return int.Parse(r["MsgID"].ToString()) + 1;`

there error:

> Column 'MsgID' does not belong to table Table.

but what I have also noticed that it gets into the `if (r.Read())` even if there is nothing in the table.

I have checked couple of times, the name of the table and the `CON_STR` are both correct and there is a column named `MsgID` in the table

Answer (score 0):

Add column name here  `Select MAX(MsgID) as MsgID FROM Msgs`

Comment: it made a different error in the same line: "Input string was not in a correct format."